# How to show that using gamma function definition

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

there exists **a** $\in [1,\infty )$ s.t.$$ \int_a^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t} dt \le 2e^{\frac{-a}{2}} $$, where $x\gt 0$

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_a^\infty e^{-(1-\epsilon) t}dt = \frac{e^{-(1-\epsilon)a}}{1-\epsilon}$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**:

Let $I(a;x)$ be given by

$$I(a;x)=\int_a^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}\,dt-2e^{-a/2}$$

for $a\ge 1$ and $x>0$.

Clearly, we have $\lim_{a\to \infty}I(a;x)=0$.  In addition, for any fixed $x>0$

$$\frac{\partial I(a;x)}{\partial a}=e^{-a}\left(e^{a/2}-a^{x-1}\right)>0$$

for sufficiently large $a$.

Comment: Why did this receive a down vote??